# Not able to create docker image of .net core web API - COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/../netcoreapp2.1/publish

Tags: docker, .net-core

I'm trying to build an image of a .netcore v2.2 WebAPI app from docker file. But I'm getting a "no such file or directory" error while I try to build the image using following command:

```bsh
docker build -t helloworld .
```

I have both microsoft/dotnet "latest" and "2.2-aspnetcore-runtime" base images installed in my machine.

Here's my docker file

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet

RUN mkdir /app
COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2 /app
WORKDIR /app

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "/app/HelloWorld.dll"]

# ASP.NET Core: Kestrel should listen on all IPs
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://0.0.0.0:5000"
```

Here's the folder structure of my solution (I tried the command inside the src):

[image: Folder Structure]

Here's the output directory
[image: output directory]

Here's the full error details from the docker:

```bsh
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/tmp/docker-builder896068669/bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2: no such file or directory
```

Comment: please post your folder structure

Comment: folder structure included

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may change `./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2` to `./bin/release/netcoreapp2.2`

folder names are case sensitive

Answer (score 1):

It seems the file `./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.2/publish` does not exists on the machine on which you are running `docker build`

When you run `docker build -t helloworld .` it will copy all the file in `.` (i.e. the current directory from which you run the command) to the *build context* which will then be used when running `COPY` instructions, so you need to make sure you are running your command from the proper directory where files will be available to `COPY`

You can also run the same command from another directory by specifying the path to be used as build context such as `docker build -t helloworld /path/to/my/dir`

Comment: yes, there was an extra folder "/publish" at the end of COPY command. I just removed that and I'm still getting the same error. I have updated the question with new command and the output folder structure. Can you please have a look?